# Displaying more than one of an item in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

(The question isn't worded very well so if you think you can rephrase it better then please do.)
I have basically got ten panes that are pretty much identical displayed on the PyGame screen. However the code is stupidly long and so I was wondering if there was a better way of doing what I have done.

```
def addPane(self, textToDisplay):
    #right now it is displaying them all change so that it checks how many
    #panes are on through (numberOfPanes = 0) 10 is limit display no more
    #than ten.
    paneOne = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
    paneTwo = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (0, 0, 200, 100), 2)
    paneThree = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (600, 400, 200, 100), 2)
    paneFour = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
    paneFive = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
    paneSix = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
    paneSeven = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
    paneEight = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
    paneNine = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
    paneTen = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
    if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
        print("Limit reached")
    else:
        paneOne
        self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
        if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
            print("Limit reached")
        else:
            paneTwo
            self.screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
            self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
            if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
                print("Limit reached")
            else:
                paneThree
                self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
                if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
                    print("Limit reached")
                else:
                    paneThree
                    self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
                    if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
                        print("Limit reached")
                    else:
                        paneFour
                        self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
                        if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
                            print("Limit reached")
                        else:
                            paneFive
                            self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
                            if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
                                print("Limit reached")
                            else:
                                paneSix
                                self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
                                if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
                                    print("Limit reached")
                                else:
                                    paneSeven
                                    self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
                                    if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
                                        print("Limit reached")
                                    else:
                                        paneEight
                                        self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
                                        if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
                                            print("Limit reached")
                                        else:
                                            paneNine
                                            self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
                                            if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
                                                print("Limit reached")
                                            else:
                                                paneTen
                                                self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
    pygame.display.update()
```

What it looks like:
[image: Code when run]

The text that is written in the function is what I want to achieve. I have done this but as I said earlier, it is stupidly long. Is this the best way of achieving the outcome that I already have or is there a better way of doing it?

(I will change the co-ordinates later on so that all ten panes are visible however I have done it like this for test purposes.)

Comment: You could store all your panes in a list and use a for loop to generate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this.

```
def addPane(self, text_to_display):
  pane_locs = [(175, 75, 200, 100), 
               (0, 0, 200, 100),
               (600, 400, 200, 100),
               (175, 75, 200, 100),
               (175, 75, 200, 100),
               (175, 75, 200, 100),
               (175, 75, 200, 100),
               (175, 75, 200, 100),
               (175, 75, 200, 100),
               (175, 75, 200, 100),
              ]
  for i, pane_loc in enumerate(pane_locs):
    if self.num_panes > 10:
       print("limit reached")
       break
    if i == 1:
      self.screen.blit(self.font.render(text_to_display, True, (black)), (250, 115))
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), pane_loc, 2)
    self.num_panes += 1
    pygame.display.update()
```

We're iterating over the pane locations, adding text when we're at the correct pane, and stopping when we have enough panes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
panes = []
def addPane(self, textToDisplay):
    #starting coordinate location for your frames
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(10):
        panes.append(pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (x, y, 200, 100), 2))
        panes[-1]
        #increment coordiantes by desired ammounts
        x += 200
        y += 100
        if len(panes) > 10:
            print("Limit reached")
            break
    pygame.display.update()
```